# What is the benefit of cast()

Tags: sql-server

What is the benefit of cast() here?

```
SELECT Grp_number
    ,Mobile
    ,cast(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) Card
FROM PROFILE
WHERE country = 'United Arab Emirates'
```

Thanks in advance,
Nishant

Comment: to set the data type for column `Card` as `varchar(10)`

Comment: @Squirrel then what is the difference between above query & below query: select Grp_number, Mobile, null Card 
from profile where country = 'United Arab Emirates'

Comment: Both the queries are going to return the same result as the `Card` column is not used for any other comparison. If `cast()` is not used, the `card` column will have the data type it initally had, and NOT `varchar(10)`

Comment: for `NULL card`, the data type is not defined, some client may not able to determine the data type. For select into example `SELECT NULL Card INTO table_name`, it will be default to `integer`. With `CAST()`, the data type is as what you defined in the `CAST()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `CAST` you will get column with data type `INT`.

```
SELECT Grp_number
    ,Mobile
    ,cast(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) Card       -- VARCHAR(10)
FROM PROFILE
WHERE country = 'United Arab Emirates'

SELECT Grp_number
    ,Mobile
    ,NULL Card                            -- INT
FROM PROFILE
WHERE country = 'United Arab Emirates';
```

This may cause  problems with data type mapping (ORM/SSIS/reporting tools).

Comment: This is correct and can be prove easily: `exec sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'SELECT NULL as x'  ` vs `exec sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'SELECT cast(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) as x'  `

Answer (score 0):

The data type of `Card` may not have been set as `varchar(10)` initially. `Cast()` helps to explicitly set the column as varchar(10) here.